# How to make this do-while loop stop when the input is out of range?

Tags: java

I've been working on this for hours! I feel like the solution might be really easy but I just can't see it out for the life of me.

I want to know how to make the do-while loop in the userInput() part actually stop when the user input for var1 or var 2 is outside of the range. Less than 0 or greater than 10. Here's the original question:

modify PlayLife so the user can enter a series of
 row, col coordinates between 1 and 10 to make cells alive. Entering a value
 less than 1 or greater than 10 will be the signal the user is done.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PlayLife
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{int answer;
    World myWorld = new World(10, 10);

    System.out.println("Enter a row and column number between 1 and 10 to make a cell live:");
    myWorld.userInput();
    System.out.println(myWorld);
    System.out.println();`
```

World

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class World
{
    private Cell[][] board;  //a 2 dimensional array of Cells called board
    private int rows;
    private int cols;
    int var1 = 0, var2 = 0 , test;
    int row, col;

public World(int numOfRows, int numOfCols)
{
    int row, col;
    rows = numOfRows;
    cols = numOfCols;
    board = new Cell[rows][cols];
            //the following nested loop creates the rows X cols array of "dead" Cells

    for(row = 0; row < rows; row++)
        for(col = 0; col < cols; col++)
            board[row][col] = new Cell(false); 
}

public boolean getStatus(int row, int col)
{
    return board[row][col].getStatus();
}
public void setStatus(int row, int col, boolean status)
{
    board[row][col].setStatus(status);
}
public void makeAlive(int row, int col)
{
    board[row][col].setStatus(true);
}
public void makeDead(int row, int col)
{
    board[row][col].setStatus(false);
}
public void userInput()
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    for(col = 0; col < cols; col++)
        for(row = 0; row < rows; row++)
            do
            {
                var1 = keyboard.nextInt();
                var2 = keyboard.nextInt();
            }
            while(var1 < 0 || var1 >= 10 || var2 < 0 || var2 >= 10);
        board[var1][var2].setStatus(true);


}           
public void randomFill()
{
    int row, col;
    Random pick = new Random();
    for(row = 0 ; row < rows; row++)
        for(col = 0; col < cols; col++)
            if(pick.nextInt(4)==0)  //make 25% of the cells alive 
                board[row][col].setStatus(true);
}

public String toString()
{
    String boardPic = "";  //start with an empty string
    int row, col;

    for(row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        for(col = 0; col < cols; col++)
            if(board[row][col].getStatus())
                boardPic = boardPic + "X"; //if the cell is alive, add an X to it
            else
                boardPic = boardPic + "."; //otherwise adda dot
        boardPic = boardPic + "\n";                //after finishing all columns in a row, add a newline character
    }
    return boardPic;
}
    // counts all live cells in a 3 X 3 array then subtracts 1 if the center cell is alive
private int countNeighbors(int curRow, int curCol)
{
    int row, col, neighbors = 0;

    for(row = curRow - 1; row <= curRow + 1; row++)
        for(col = curCol - 1; col <= curCol + 1; col++)
            if(board[row][col].getStatus())
                neighbors++;

            //Is the center cell alive?
    if(board[curRow][curCol].getStatus())
        neighbors--;
    return neighbors;
}
    //The outside edge is already dead, so this only processes row 1-8 and column 1-8
    //if a cell has three neighbors, it will be alive regardless of its current status
    //if a cell has two neighbors, it will be the same in the next gen as the last.
public void nextGen()
{
    World nextOne = new World(rows, cols);  //makes a new "scratch" array
    int row, col, neighbors;

    for(row = 1; row < rows - 1; row++)
        for(col = 1; col < cols - 1; col++)
        {
            neighbors = countNeighbors(row, col);
            if(neighbors == 3)
                nextOne.makeAlive(row, col);
            else if (neighbors == 2)
                nextOne.setStatus(row, col, this.getStatus(row, col));  //"this" refers to the object performing the method
        }
    //copy new world just created to exixting world
    for(row = 0; row < rows; row++)
        for(col = 0; col < cols; col++)
            board[row][col].setStatus(nextOne.board[row][col].getStatus());
    }
}
```

and here's the other one. There's nothing wrong with this one I'm just posting it just in case you'd like to see it

```
   public class Cell
{

private boolean status;  //true = alive, false = dead

public Cell(boolean aliveOrDead)  //one parameter constructor
{
    status = aliveOrDead;
}

public void setStatus(boolean aliveOrDead)  //mutator to set the status of the cell via the parameter
{
    status = aliveOrDead;
}

public boolean getStatus()  //acessor to get the current status
{
    return status;
}
}
```

Comment: `do { // ... } while ((var1 > 0 && var1 < 10) && (var2 > 0 && var2 < 10))` should do the trick.

Comment: You should probably fix your indentation so it makes sense.

Comment: Oh sorry about that! I'm new here so I'm just getting the hang of posting code. In my actual program the indentation is correct though.

Answer (score 0):

Seth is right. The expression you use inside your while is not correct for what you are trying to achieve. If you replace it with the code Seth gave you you should be fine. 
Right now your code executes only for the values for which you DONT want it to execute.

So something like this

```
do
            {
                var1 = keyboard.nextInt();
                var2 = keyboard.nextInt();
            }
            while((var1 > 0 && var1 < 10) && (var2 > 0 && var2 < 10));
```